# While debugging a class in Java Eclipse IDE, I am facing error "Failed to Connect to remote VM. Connection Refused. Connection Refused: connect"

Tags: eclipse, debugging, configuration, remote-debugging

> Failed to Connect to remote VM. Connection Refused. Connection Refused: connect

Kindly help me fix this issue with steps in details where ever required to configure the changes in Eclipse IDE. I am using wildfly version 13.0 (J Boss)
Eclipse Version 2023.03 (Community Edition)

Eclipse error

[image]

I did debug configuration settings. In Connection Properties i set the port to 8000 but nothing working and resolving my issue.

Can someone address this with screenshots to make it easier to solve?

Eclipse debug configuration

[image]

Comment: Eclipse does not have a "Community Edition", but regardless, are you sure your firewall is allowing Java to accept incoming connections?

Comment: @nitind yes no restriction there and firewall is allowed to accept all incoming connections

Comment: Are there changes that need to be made in the WildFly setup to make it accept debug clients?